# Dojo ResizeHandle Working example

Tags: javascript, dojo, resize

The documentation for the DOJO ResizeHandle is a little sketchy, and the examples are not "working examples" like in other documentation pages.

Does anyone have a working example of a ResizeHandle?  I know its experimental, but if it works for my use case I would like to use it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have to declare it, and tell it the target div to use,  that div has to be relative.

```
<div id="child" class="child" data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ResizeHandle" data-dojo-props="targetId:'parent'">
```

ex.
https://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/6t9pyhrx/